# C# UWP: "cannot convert string to byte[]/System.DateTime/bool"

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I have created a User registration page on UWP which allows the user to enter their registration details, then click a button to update the database with that information:

```
int i = await wcf.RegisterUserAsync(UserNameBox.Text, 
                                    PasswordBox.Text, 
                                    FirstNameBox.Text, 
                                    LastNameBox.Text,
                                    DateOfBirthBox.Text, 
                                    EULicenseBox.Text, 
                                    NonEULicenseBox.Text, 
                                    EmailBox.Text, 
                                    ContactNumberBox.Text);
```

I only used textboxes - even for fields that require `DateTime`, `byte[]` and `bool`. The error I am receiving is the following:

> "cannot convert string to byte[]/System.DateTime/bool".

I understand that I must convert but I do not know how.

Comment: First dont use textboxes for other types of data. If you must you have to /should convert it to the proper datatypes before passing it to the function call for proper validation, then you can capture the issues if the datatypes do not match you can default the values or return an error to the user

Comment: How do I convert them?

Comment: How to convert them depends on the input the user is expected to type in and the input the `RegisterUserAsync` method expects. For example, for the boolean type, is the user expected to type `yes` or `no` or are they expected to type `true` or `false` or `1` or `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic .Net types have a Parse and TryParse method which takes strings that you can use to try to parse the string to the value.

```
DateTime dateOfBirth;

if (DateTime.TryParse(DateOfBirthBox.Text, out dateOfBirth))
{
   // dateOfBirth was parsed successfully and is valid.
}
```

Comment: In the latest version of C' you can write it like this: if (DateTime.TryParse(DateOfBirthBox.Text, out DateTime dateOfBirth))
{
   // dateOfBirth was parsed successfully and is valid.
}